# How do I access the contents of the current region in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, region

I want to access the contents of the current region as a string within a function.  For example:

```
(concat "stringa" (get-region-as-string) "stringb")
```

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[`buffer-substring`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html) together with `region-beginning` and `region-end` can do that.

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you.  I definitely wouldn't have found that by myself.

Answer (score 82):

As starblue says, `(buffer-substring (mark) (point))` returns the contents of the region, if the mark is set.  If you do not want the [string properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html), you can use the `'buffer-substring-no-properties` variant.

However, if you're writing an *interactive* command, there's a better way to get the endpoints of the region, using the form `(interactive "r")`. Here's an example from `simple.el`:

```
(defun count-lines-region (start end)
  "Print number of lines and characters in the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (message "Region has %d lines, %d characters"
       (count-lines start end) (- end start)))
```

When called from Lisp code, the `(interactive ...)` form is ignored, so you can use this function to count the lines in *any* part of the buffer, not just the region, by passing the appropriate arguments: for example, `(count-lines-region (point-min) (point-max))` to count the lines in the narrowed part of the buffer. But when called interactively, the `(interactive ...)` form is evaluated, and the `"r"` code supplies the point and the mark, as two numeric arguments, smallest first.

See the Emacs Lisp Manual, sections [21.2.1 Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html#Using-Interactive) and [21.2.2 Code Characters for interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to copy region content in a Lisp code to a user-accessible data structure like kill-ring, X clipboard or register, Emacs Lisp manual recommends to use [`filter-buffer-substring`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html#index-filter_002dbuffer_002dsubstring-2827) instead of simply `buffer-substring`. Before copying, the function applies filter functions from a list variable called [`filter-buffer-substring-functions`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html#index-filter_002dbuffer_002dsubstring_002dfunctions-2828). The function was [added in version 22.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.22.3).