# How to get selected text in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to get selection as a string in my Emacs Lisp function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Selected text is called region in Emacs universe. See [How do I access the contents of the current region in Emacs Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605846/how-do-i-access-the-contents-of-the-current-region-in-emacs-lisp/605931#605931)

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer pointed me to the right answer. I want to leave this piece of code for more ELisp beginners like me. `regionp` contains the "selection" (known as region in ELisp) as a variable in the ELisp function. The `if` condition checks if the region is active.

```
(defun get-selected-text (start end)
  (interactive "r")
    (if (use-region-p)
        (let ((regionp (buffer-substring start end)))
            (message regionp))))
```