# Advice for "kill-ring-save"

Tags: elisp

I want to evaluate certain conditions before allowing a user to copy a text. As far as I know, I need an advice for `"kill-ring-save"`. I need to ignore the user request to Copy that text if conditions are not met and allow it if are satisfied. How can I do this?

(UPDATE)
-- MORE ABOUT CONSTRAINTS: only in specific mode of Emacs (e.g. NXML mode) this advice should be applied and only when one/more specific conditions are met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick proof of concept; you don't tell what your constraints are, so this is necessarily vague / useless.

```
(defvar moo nil)

(defadvice kill-ring-save (around kill-ring-check-constraints activate compile)
  "If in `nxml-mode', don't save to kill ring if `moo' is `nil'."
  (if (and (eq major-mode 'nxml-mode) (null moo))
    (message "Not copied.")
   ad-do-it) )
```

The additional major-mode constraint was added in response to comments below.  If you want this in every mode, just take out the mode check.

Comment: The edit iss exactly what I needed. I will also add it to the question.

Comment: One small issue, If I want to read the value that is copied and check for example if it doesn't have "JACK" in it, can I do it with advice too? I want it to be dynamic though, so for example I can check for different Strings.. I can update the question or write another one if you can't answer here. it is related to this question though.

Comment: You could examine the current region, either by searching in the buffer between point and mark, or by copying the region to a string. Quick googling turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605846/how-do-i-access-the-contents-of-the-current-region-in-emacs-lisp