# Getting the extreme points of selected text

Tags: emacs, elisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access the contents of the current region in Emacs Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605846/how-do-i-access-the-contents-of-the-current-region-in-emacs-lisp)

(point) can be used to find the position of the cursor in elisp.
Is there any similar function which returns the beginning and the ending point of a region of selected text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Emacs, "the region", which may or may not be highlighted, lies between `(point)` and `(mark)`.

Since mark can be positioned before or after point, the utility functions `region-beginning` and `region-end` will return the smaller and the larger of the two, respectively.

`(mark)` will return `nil` if the mark has never been set in the buffer, in which case both `region-beginning` and `region-end` will signal an error. A non-nil value of mark doesn't imply that a region is currently highlighted. Whether the region is considered active is also affected by `transient-mark-mode` and `mark-even-if-inactive` options. The function `use-region-p` can be used to test whether it is appropriate to act on the region.